# How do I analytically list the correct sequence for the given digital circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines

Suppose given the digital circuit below, which contains 3 JK flip-flops:

[image]

Assume that the sequence starts at ABC = 000.  How can I analytically list the resulting sequence after every clock cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it helps to know that the characteristic equation for a JK flip-flop is:

$$Q^+=JQ'+K'Q$$

Where \$Q\$ is the output of the JK flip-flop, and \$Q^+\$ is the next output of \$Q\$ after a clock cycle.

Then we derive state equations A, B, and C for every clock cycle. For the output A:

$$A^+ = J_AA'+K_A'A$$

Since \$J_A = K_A = 1\$:

$$A^+=A'$$

For the output B:
$$B^+=J_BB'+K_B'B$$
Since \$J_B = C'\$ and \$K_B = C\$:
$$B^+=C'B'+C'B$$
Which can simplified to:
$$B^+=C'$$
For the output C:
$$C^+=J_CC'+K_C'C$$
Since \$J_C = B'\$ and \$K_C = B\$: 
$$C^+=B'C'+B'C$$
Which can simplified to:
$$C^+=B'$$
Also, notice that the clock input of the JK flip-flop with output C is connected to the output A.  Therefore, that JK flip-flop is triggered only when A goes from 1 to 0.  In summary, the state equations are:

$$A^+=A'$$
$$B^+=C'$$
$$C^+=B' \space \text{(when $A = 1 \rightarrow 0$)}$$

We can then list the sequence based on the state equations above:

$$ 000 \rightarrow 110 \rightarrow 010 \rightarrow 110 \rightarrow 010 ...$$